# Discard 200 random healthy instances

Tags: r, bigdata

Discard 200 random healthy instances.
How do I implement this in Rstudio?

This is the data frame:

https://www.kaggle.com/code/jamaltariqcheema/model-performance-and-comparison/data

I tried this but I got an error.

```
kidney_disease$hd <- ifelse(test=kidney_disease$hd == 0, yes="Healthy", no="Unhealthy")
```

Comment: To discard 200 rows, try `kidney_disease[-sample(nrow(kidney_disease), 200),]`.

Comment: I first want to separate it into healthy and unhealthy instances, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following solves the question's problem.
Choose row numbers at random with `sample`, assign a default value `"Healthy"` to the new column `hd` and assign the value `"Unhealthy"` to the randomly chosen rows.

```
set.seed(2022)   # Make results reproducible

i <- sample(nrow(kidney_disease), 200)
kidney_disease$hd <- "Healthy"
kidney_disease$hd[i] <- "Unhealthy"
```